# Raster layer to GeoTIFF QGIS Python

Tags: pyqgis

Is there a way to export a layer in GeoTIFF format from Python? I am able to perform georeference with Python and show the results on the canvas. However, when I am inserting the .tif file in any third party program like AutoCAD, then the georeference is not right.

However, the very same .tif file, when loaded to QGIS, even in a different project, works like a charm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Solved

```
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(self.full_path)
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    rlayer = getLayerByName(fname)
    provider = rlayer.dataProvider()

    if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
        return
    file_writer.writeRaster(
        pipe,
        provider.xSize(),
        provider.ySize(),
        provider.extent(),
        provider.crs())
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to jump in here and make sure you've set your AutoCAD file in the right CRS and are using the MAPIINSERT command in AutoCAD.